# Unable to call a function in R

Tags: r, time, series

I am trying to run a function called "RHtests V4" from http://etccdi.pacificclimate.org/software.shtml" to homogenize my climate data time series. However when I try to call the function using the
`source("RHtestsV4.r")` command it gives me the following error message as

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'RHtestsV4.r': No such file or directory
```

I have made sure that my current working directory contains the code file with the same name. Can anyone help me to overcome the issue?
Thanks
Som

Comment: What is your working directory? Check `getwd()` and see if that matches the location of your file `RHtestsV4.r`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I checked my working directory using getwd(). It does contain the RHtests V4 text file which is also confirmed using the dir() command. I don't know what might be causing this error. Any other ideas please?

Comment: This probably isn't the solution, but every time you mention the file, there is a space in between "RHtests" and "V4", but there isn't a space in the error code. Did you type the filename incorrectly?

Comment: Can you paste in the output of `list.files()`?  That might give us a clue as to why R is not finding the file.

Comment: The filename isn't supposed to have any space between RHtests and V4. I made sure this is the case, So filename and the name being called in the command are consistent. My apologies for the confusion while typing with an extra space here in the forum...

Comment: The output of list.files() is too long to be pasted in one comment so I will try to paste that in several replies. But I can see the text file there already..

Comment: "RHtestsV4.r.txt" -here is how it shows up for the file name in that directory

Comment: You should remove the .txt from the file name